What property causes the supremum to be adherent point for $\mathbb{R}$?
In general, supremum is defined as the least upper bound. In the case of $\mathbb{R}$, we have an alternative characterization that $\text{sup} S $ is the supremum of a set $S$ if and only if for all epsilon, there exist an $s \in S$ so that $  \text{sup} S -\epsilon< s$. Theorem-1
I am trying to figure out which property of $\mathbb{R}$ allows us to show the alternative characterization of supremum. I know that it can't directly be out of the supremums axiom since $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ also satisfy this but do not have this property *.

Can you state the "alternative characterization" more carefully? What's the epsilon doing?

Made a mistake in phrasing. Corrected it now @Karl

Do you want to say "$a = \sup S$ if for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists an $s \in S$ such that $a - \epsilon < s$?

Exactly @Jay....

The characterisation is not entirely correct: you also need that $\sup S$ is an upper bound. (Otherwise all numbers less than some $s\in S$ are the supremum).
The proof uses the fact that $p > s$ if and only if there exists $p-s = \epsilon > 0$ as well as the fact the $\mathbb{R}$ is totally ordered.
Note that the characterisation does actually hold for $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$. In this case $\epsilon > 0$ should be interpreted to mean that $\epsilon \in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$.

Isn't supremums by definition an upper bound?

Yes. For a number $x$ to be the supremum of $S$ it must satisfy two conditions: (1) $x$ must be an upper bound of $S$ and (2) each upper bound of $S$ must be larger than or equal to $x$. The statement you claim is equivalent to $x$ being the supremum of $S$ is actually only equivalent to (2), not (1), and thus does not fully characterise the supremum.
